# Bootstrap selectpicker val won't accept an object just string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, twitter-bootstrap

I want to understand one behavior from `selectpicker`.  I'm trying load this this element with one attribute from my session:

```
Template.checkNotification.onRendered(function () {
    var currentNotification = Session.get("currentNotification");

    this.$('#symptoms1').selectpicker({
        multipleSeparator: ' ',
    });

    this.$('#symptoms2').selectpicker({
        multipleSeparator: ' ',
    });

    var symptoms = [];
    for (var symptom of currentNotification.symptom.symptoms) {
        symptoms.push('"' + symptom.name + ';;' + symptom.value + '"');
    }
    var symptomsSelected = symptoms.join(", ");

    var test1 = ['Dor de Cabeça;;dor-de-cabeca','Náusea;;nausea'];
    var test2 = "["+symptomsSelected+"]";

    this.$('#symptoms1').selectpicker('val', test1);
    this.$('#symptoms2').selectpicker('val', test2);
});
```

When I execute this code, only the element `#symptom1` works and loads the proper options into the `selectpicker`.

How can I build an array of option to provide to `selectpicker`?

Comment: $scope.symptomsSelected="["+'"\My selected item is string\"'+"]"
$scope.test2 =angular.fromJson($scope.symptomsSelected);
$scope.test2=$scope.test2[0];

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the symptoms to the `selectpicker`, you need to provide it as a native array.  This code builds the array the original way and the new way (suitable for assigning to the `val`):

```js
var currentNotification = {
  symptom: {
    symptoms: [
      { name: "symptom1", value: "value1" },
      { name: "symptom2", value: "value2" },
      { name: "symptom3", value: "value3" },
      { name: "symptom4", value: "value4" },
      { name: "symptom5", value: "value5" }
    ]
  }
};

var symptoms = [];
for (var symptom of currentNotification.symptom.symptoms) {
  symptoms.push('"' + symptom.name + ';;' + symptom.value + '"');
}

var symptomsSelected = symptoms.join(", ");
var test1 = "["+symptomsSelected+"]";

var test2 = $.map(currentNotification.symptom.symptoms, function(symptom) {
  return symptom.name + ';;' + symptom.value;
});

console.log("test1: ", typeof test1, " value: ", test1);
console.log("test2: ", typeof test2, " value: ", test2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How does this work?  The jQuery [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) function will process each of the symptoms from the `currentNotification.symptom.symptoms` array, and format them individually for use with `selectpicker`.  Each element is formatted, but the array is left as a native Javascript array, with each element corresponding to the original `currentNotification.symptom.symptoms` array.

Compare the results of `test1` and `test2` to see the difference:

```
test1:  string  value:  ["symptom1;;value1", "symptom2;;value2", "symptom3;;value3", "symptom4;;value4", "symptom5;;value5"]
test2:  object  value:  [
  "symptom1;;value1",
  "symptom2;;value2",
  "symptom3;;value3",
  "symptom4;;value4",
  "symptom5;;value5"
]
```

Note that in this example code, `test1` is a string, which is formatted like an array.  This resembles a JSON array value, not a native Javascript array value.  `test2` is a Javascript array suitable for use with `selectpicker`.

Using the `$.map` solution will solve your current problem and produce a proper Javascript array.  Now, you can use this to set the `val` of the `selectpicker`:

```
this.$('#symptoms2').selectpicker('val', test2);
```

Answer (score -1):

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/sjwK1e?p=preview

```js
$scope.symptomsSelected="["+'"\My selected item is string\"'+"]"
$scope.test2 =angular.fromJson($scope.symptomsSelected);
$scope.test2=$scope.test2[0];
```

```html
  {{test2}}
  <br>
  {{symptomsSelected}}
```